# How do steel and enforced concrete posts compare?

Tags: concrete, materials, steel

From what I observe in my region posts in both municipal and private construction - mostly fence posts and lighting posts - are gradually replaced from enforced concrete to steel pipes.

Is it just my region or is there a fundamental reason to prefer steel pipes to enforced concrete? I mean steel corrodes if not maintained regularly and enforced concrete doesn't seem to change over time at all so enforced concrete seems more practical.

How do steel and enforced concrete posts compare? Why prefer steel posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that there is also a safety angle here. Steel pipes tend to bend and fall over if hit by cars etc, therefore have a better impact for the ones that hit it. Concrete on the other hand does not tend to bend and therefore will cause a lot more damage to those that run into it. Of course this may have nothing to do with what you are seeing.

Here in the UK they are also rolling out collapsible frames that are used for large road signs as well so that if cars hit them they only cause minor damage to the vehicle as they bend and collapse around the car.

edit: The frames are known as Lattix. [Lattix Website](http://www.lattix.net/)

The safety aspects are demonstrated here. [Lattix Safety](http://www.lattix.net/index.php/site/safety_full/genuine_pliant_masts/)

Answer (score 1):

from the overall cost-value perspective i think that the steel pipes are cheaper.

Comment: Does this include preventing corrosion?

Comment: @sharptooth: Maybe. I'm not sure, it's just an assumption. in my area enforced concrete isn't used at all for this applications. only steel pipes...